# What can I do about closed questions on the purpose of F# that show up in Google results?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

I have tried to Google the topic "Purpose of F#" and the top 2 results are from Stack Overflow. Both are closed.

Both link to other articles on the Stack Exchange network which are also closed, which in turn link to other articles which are also closed or broken/deleted. I'm surprised that such a basic question as this would have readers jumping from topic to topic only to find that none of them are in fact appropriate in the end. It would seem more constructive to me to have someplace along the chain be an actual answer to the question, even if it's an external link. Or simply eliminate/avoid providing the links if they link to similarly closed topics.

These are the web of topics I found in my trip down the F# rabbit hole:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190472/what-is-the-purpose-of-f
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080130/why-would-i-learn-f
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202802/why-you-i-should-not-learn-another-language
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141985/why-should-a-net-developer-learn-f
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52313/what-is-the-f-language
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648446/for-which-purposes-is-f-preferred-to-other-languages-and-what-are-its-strength
- [What are the benefits of using C# vs F# or F# vs C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952318/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-c-sharp-vs-f-or-f-vs-c)

Is there anything I/we can do to help clean it up?

Comment: Just from reading the titles of those questions I can guess that they are opinion-based and thus off-topic.

Comment: "Purpose of F#" is an unsuitable question for [so], so gets closed. What is your suggestion? That whenever a question is to be closed the closers first google for an answer and link to it?

Comment: So what is someone supposed to do with this question, ignore results that least to stackoverflow and otherstackexchange sites?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - Not much we can do about google crawling the sites. Closed questions of this sort should be deleted - cast your delete votes on them. We have a rather large queue of closed questions that are waiting deletion.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN If you have a question that you know isn't suitable for the SE paradigm, yes.  When you're searching for content that is suitable for the SE's design then you should be more inclined to look at the pages.

Comment: @Oded I don't have a specific suggestion, but I wanted to point this out to see if anyone agrees that this is less than ideal and see if there are any ideas on what we should do about it.

Comment: There are currently [225 closed F# questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bf%23%5D+closed%3A1) and [5,028 open F# questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bf%23%5D+closed%3A0). The answer to your question is, they're not...

Comment: What's wrong with marking a question as a duplicate of a question that is/may be closed as off topic? How would it help to mark them both as off topic?

Comment: Of course it is less than ideal. However, "closed" is not a final state in [so] - things can be reopened or deleted. Either of those states would solve the problem for a majority of such questions.

Comment: "*I have tried to Google the topic "Purpose of F#"*. Stack overflow isn't the place to come for such knowledge. As a professional site it assumes a high degree of initial knowledge of the subject, so nobody would have asked what a language is for as they'd be long past that stage by the time they start asking questions here.

Comment: @JonW I'm a professional programmer and yet I have no idea what the purpose of most languages is.  (Of course, it's still an inappropriate question on SO for entirely different reasons.)

Comment: @Servy exactly, and SO isn't the place to come to learn this. I don't know much about anything, so I never visit SO!

Comment: I would point out that one of the questions was from programmers.stackexchange.com too, which was kind of "linked" as the place that I should look for the answer in one case.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Such a question is no more appropriate on programmers than on SO.

Comment: @Servy The comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141985/why-should-a-net-developer-learn-f implies that programmers *is* a better place for the question.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN That comment is entirely incorrect.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN it looks like comment you refer to was deleted (I just searched for it, planning to flag for mod attention, requesting to remove)

Comment: I see things are already improving. If I or someone were to reword that question as "What unique language constructs in F# distinguish it from C#, VB, C++?" Would it be more suitable to reopen? Or should that be posed as a new question (despite the fact that the answer is already here) or has it been already?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there any way to clean this up?

Well... Yeah. We can delete all of them. Then they won't show up in Google anymore... I've gone and done this for a few of these questions, which - once Google updates - should make the F# Wikipedia article come out on top for your query.

Perhaps that's not the sort of cleanup you were referring to though. Well...

In theory, some of these questions could be edited to make them less subjective and more focused; in practice, putting that much effort into one of these questions would require someone sufficiently motivated to do so, perhaps by the presence of a *really good answer*. There are a couple of decent answers floating around in that mess of questions, and they're still fairly easy to find - but I don't see anyone going out of their way to dress up the questions to fit them.

At the end of the day, the problem with these questions is that... They're kinda lazy. They're the new programmer equivalent of the kid walking through his grandfather's workshop, picking up each tool in turn and asking, "What's *this* for?" Patience, child - watch and learn...

When Stack Overflow first launched, F# was still *relatively* new - so folks asked a lot of questions about it, some of which were *not very good*. [As Bill notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202618/why-are-all-questions-about-the-purpose-of-f-or-whether-to-learn-f-closed/202619#202619), there are plenty of great F# questions, but you'll still run into some of the older cruft as well. If you find something useful in it, feel free to try salvaging it - or ask for help from others who might be able to. Otherwise, don't hesitate to flag it and ask that it be removed, so as to avoid cluttering up search results for others.

Comment: I agree the questions sound rather lazy, but so does closing them and linking to another closed question (although I admit moderators have less time to dedicate to each question than the original writers and shouldn't be expected to fix it). It would be nice if the predisposition were to improving the question rather than leading readers on a wild goose chase of closed questions. Is there any way to encourage improvement of the question before closing it?

Comment: Keep in mind that some of these questions were closed as duplicates long before the questions they link to were closed for being too broad / too subjective. We've made the rules for duplicate closing much more strict since then, but there's still no way to predict the future - as the shear number of cross links indicated, this was (at one time) a *mess* of duplicate and overlapping topics, most of them poorly-asked and even more poorly-answered; this sort of cross-linking was the best the folks could do at the time.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN We don't want to encourage improvement *instead of closing*, but rather *in addition to*.  Questions are closed when they are not good questions *as they stand*.  Closing them is specifically creating an opportunity for them to be edited and improved.  If they can be improved, great; they can be reopened.  If not, they will either stay closed, or possibly just be deleted.  The site *does* encourage improvement.

Comment: On a related topic, is there anything I can do to improve *this* question to the point where it's not out of place on meta.stackoverflow.com? Seems it's not doing too well either.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Well, I'd start by just removing everything that you yourself have labeled a rant.  Rants are largely unconstructive.  If there is a point or two in there that you think could be useful, pull it out and make a constructive section about it.  Also, there this is a pretty commonly brought up topic, so in addition to being not particularly constructive, it's just repeating a bunch of stuff that's been talk about to death; it's a fairly poor question for that reason alone.

Comment: It's not *out of place* here, @Blue - it just kinda hit a sour note. Whenever possible, try to avoid hyperbole and simply state a specific problem, asking for help understanding it and finding a solution - that goes for SO *and* MSO.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive replies. I have tried to re-state my question more constructively. I forget how diplomatic I need to be when the majority of my audience might not see things from the same perspective. Or rather, I'm sometimes surprised that my perspective is so "unique" :-).

Comment: Not so much unique, @BlueMonkMN, as that your original tone sorta struck a nerve - there's a fair bit of history here (in terms of subjective questions on SO in general, and subjective F# questions specifically - going back 3-4 years, one of the top F# users on SO was a very outspoken proponent of these sorts of questions). I think your edit helps a good deal - I've tweaked it a bit more.

Comment: @Shog9 I haven't seen the word "cruft" in writing for close to 40 years.  You and I must have a common mentor somewhere back in prehistory.

Answer (score 9):

You're following a trail of off-topic questions that are all linked together.  That doesn't mean all F# questions are closed, just the ones that are a bad fit for Stack Overflow.  Go to the main [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23) page and you can see plenty of open questions.

Comment: OK, badly worded title, I suppose I should have said "F#'s purpose" instead of just "F#"

Answer (score 7):

(I have ignored the section marked as a rant)

> doesn't the fact that Google's top 2 results for a question lead to stackoverflow.com articles suggest that this is on topic and an appropriate place to deal with the question instead of closing it?

Nope.  That a question shows up in Google's results has *nothing* to do with whether or not it's on topic for the site.

> Shouldn't at least one of the links on the endless path of closed questions answer the question and remain open for discussion?

Nope, because these kinds of questions aren't appropriate for SO, specifically because we don't want *discussions* on SO, we want concrete questions with concrete answers.

Comment: Would the question "For what purpose is F# designed/ideal" be considered concrete?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN That would be "too broad" at the very least.  And also probably no, it's likely too subjective as well.

Comment: So is there no site on the stack exchange network where one can answer or discuss such a question? It seemed a good fit to me and to Google to look at stack exchange sites to answer this question. Do stack exchange sites follow dictates of founding principles or adjust to the most helpful outcome?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN The only place on the network where such a question isn't strictly prohibited would be in chat, but that's not to say that any given chatroom would actually welcome such a post.  Generally such questions are generally asked on other sites entirely.  Once upon a time such questions *were* allowed (you'll note many of these questions are quite old; some were asked when they weren't discouraged) but the problems resulting from such questions was so significant that the decision was made that the site would be *more helpful* if they were prohibited.

Comment: Probably worth noting that there are a *bunch* of questions similar to that one in the F# tag, [many of which are still open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23?sort=frequent). It was probably the single most common query early on, since... Well, since there wasn't a lot of actual F# code floating around to observe and folks were curious. I expect we'll need to keep *a few* of these for a good while, just to satisfy the urges of folks new to the language. @BlueMonkMN

Answer (score 2):

No, the fact that Google finds these questions does *not* suggest that they are on topic. Neither does it state or insinuate it. Questions are on-topic if they fit within the guidelines for on-topic questions, and all of these are way-out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental difference between the poeple who want to keep SO as a Q&A site and those who want it to serve a broader, but more diffuse need.  The two points of view can best be summarized by two questions:

How does it work?
What is it for?

SO has specialized in the first question, or actually a more limited version of it:  why doesn't it work the way I expect?

The second question is a valid one,  but it isn't what SO is for.  It's inherently subjective.  It tends to encourage open ended discussions, with opinions that are not falsifiable, and therefore can never be discarded as incorrect.  And some of the most creative users of new tools use them for purposes that the original designers neve rimagined possible.

It might be worthwhile to invent a new kind of site,  one that's dedicated to "What is it for?"  But SO and even Stack Exchange isn't that site.

Comment: Is there a site appropriate for technical questions that are out of place on SO?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Not on the SE network, for these questions at least.  As for outside of that, most technical q/a sites and forums have very little limitations on what types of questions can be asked; just take your pick.